# What's the preferred way to design navigation in a large Android application?

Tags: android

The droid application I'm currently working on is getting quite large -> many Activities. I'm concerned about the way I should design the navigation in this app.

I have a main menu Activity, which should be the only entry point to the app. If the user start from here, he/she can go quite deep, through many Activities. However, there are Activities that should be accessed by traversing multiple paths, not just 1, from the MainMenu.

By a simple example: let's say the user has a profile, which he/she can view and edit, and can also view other users profile with this Activity. The app also has a forum-like feature. These can normally be accessed from the menu like this:
Menu -> Social Menu -> Forums -> List of posts of a selected forum.
Menu -> About Me -> Profile.

The question: The user's just clicked on the avatar of a forum post's author, so I've displayed that users Profile page. Now, when the user clicks on the Back button, should I take him back to the "Forums", or back to the "About Me" menu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this is a UX issue, the best way to find the best solution is usability testing.

However, If I had to hazard a guess as to what would make the best user experience, I would rely on the [principle of least astonishment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment) for scenario.  As a user, I expect the back button to take me back.  So if I arrive at the "Profile" page from a "Forum" I'd expect to go back to the Forum.  If I arrived from a different activity, I'd expect to go back to that activity.

Answer (score 1):

You can always control which activity gets on the stack and which not, such that you control the whole flow of your application. Write down the possibilities, figure out what pressing back would get you back to in what activity and go from there. Try reasoning as a user of your app.

Answer (score 0):

Reading what you wanna do , i'm thinking in a tabHost Layout , and Group Activitys into each layer.